# MISRA Warning<The complex expression is implicitly converted to a different essential types.>

Tags: c++, misra

MISRA C++ rule: 5_0_3

Tried with one of the MISRA compliant static tool analyzer and couldn't resolve it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint32_t num = 0U;
    bool Flag =false;

    num |= (Flag ? (0b10 << 10):(0b00 << 10));
}
```

Please help in getting resolve this.
Error messages are:
1. The non-constant operands to this binary bitwise operator have different essential types.
2. This complex expression is implicitly converted to a different essential type.

Comment: All the numeric literals (except the `0U` you use to initialize `num`) are of type `int`. That means the result of the conditional expression will also be an `int`.

Comment: Also note that MISRA is exceptionally strict for almost all general programming. Unless your requirements include MISRA clean code then you should not use it for checking your code.

Comment: ^^^ So, try using `0b10u`.

Comment: Did MISRA-C++ actually use the term "essential type"? MISRA-C++ seems mostly similar to MISRA-C:2004 and it used to be "underlying type" in 2004, prior MISRA-C:2012. It has a slightly different meaning, basically 2012 speaks of type categories instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `0b` syntax is non-standard, so there's no telling what it will do. That syntax alone is a MISRA violation; I'd recommend to use hex constants instead. At any rate, your code shouldn't contain any "magic numbers".

If we assume that your compiler treats non-standard `0b` integer constants as it treats regular decimal integer constants, then their type is (signed) `int`. The result of your operation is of signed int, "essentially signed" as MISRA would call it. But you store it in a `uin32_t` which is essentially unsigned, which is a MISRA violation and the reason for the error.

Please note that the shift operators always have the type of the integer promoted left operand. So writing something like `0b10 << 10u` wouldn't help. As a rule of thumb, *never* use bitwise operators on signed operands.

Also note that the `?:` is peculiar as it contains an implicit conversion of the 2nd and 3rd operands - they are balanced to the same type (according to "the usual arithmetic conversions"). This can create subtle bugs, so it is best to stay clear of `?:` when using small integer types or signed types (or when using MISRA, for that matter).

I would also recommend to re-write the code to something with less "magic numbers":

```
#define MASK_SOMETHING  (0x2u << 10) // give this some meaningful name
#define MASK_EMPTY      (0x0u << 10) // give this some meaningful name

uint32_t num = 0U;
bool Flag = false;

...

if(Flag)
{
  num |= MASK_SOMETHING;
}
```

Obviously bitwise OR against zero isn't very meaningful, maybe you meant to clear the bits instead if the Flag isn't set? In which case you need `else { num &= ~MASK_EMPTY; }`.

(This can also be optimized further to get rid of the branch.)

Comment: `0b` is standard since C+14

Comment: @Caleth MISRA-C++ only allows C++03 so that's quite irrelevant.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the logic you suggested. Instead of using conditional operator(?:) it is splitted in if else condition then the MISRA warnings are cleared. Thanks for the other suggestions.